# Lenovo ideapad s340- 15iil does not boot from usb stick (ubuntu 16.04 installed on it )

Tags: boot, usb

I have a new  Lenovo  ideapad s340- 15i il  it worked fine using preinstalled windows 10. I tried to boot from a USB stick (Ubuntu 16.04 installed on it ) it does not boot from that flash stick. I can boot the same stick on my other laptop and desktop, please help me to resolve this issue 
Thanks
Saleh